# t_string php error

Tags: php

```
<?php
$meta_keys = explode(',' stripslashes($row['meta_keys'])); // split into individual keys at commas

foreach ($meta_keys as $key) // loop through all keys
{
    echo '<a href="#">' . trim($key) . '</a> '; // output each key link remove any leading/trailing spaces as well
}

?>
```

I think It has something to do with how I have the parenthesis, but the error it gives me is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'stripslashes' (T_STRING) in /post.php on line 91

and 91 is: $meta_keys = explode(',' stripslashes($row['meta_keys']));

you guys know what it is? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the comma after the first parameter:

```
explode(',', stripslashes($row['meta_keys']));
```

Answer (score 0):

`explode(',' stripslashes($row['meta_keys']));` Change it to :

`explode(',', $row['meta_keys']);`

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: No, `explode` splits a string into an array. `implode` goes the other way.